# JQuery not working on redirection

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, jsonp, redirect

I have an iframe within div

```
<div>
<iframe pageB>
</div>
```

on button click in iframe, redirected to a different page A - I have a jquery to hide the div on page load of A - so this part of jquery is not working - normal alert window on this page load works - I saw $ undefined - included jquery exclusively on pageA but still undefined error has gone but jquery does not work - can any body shed some light on this? doesnt jquery work in this redirection scenario.

Comment: You may need to post your jQuery code.

Comment: window.onload = function() {
    alert('test');
     $('#abc').stop(true).animate({'right':'0px'},100);
    }

Answer (score 0):

If the `IFRAME` is on a different domain than the `DIV` this will not work due to security restrictions.

Instead of an `IFRAME` you could try using [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to put the content into your div, and then hide the `DIV` as a part of the callback to `load()`. This will only require jQuery to be loaded on your main page.

Comment: yes it is on different domain - but here the redirected page is on my domain - which has js on page load, it should work in that case right